# Why does a root locus show that system is stable but unit step response of a system does not have a stable output?

Tags: transfer-function, control-systems, step-response

From what I know about root locus is that if all roots are located on the Left Half of the S-plane the system is stable. That's why I expected the unit step response of a system to be stable.

Transfer function:
$$ G(s) = \frac{1+s}{s(s+1)^{2}} $$

After I plotted the locus and step response in Matlab, I got stuck.

[image]

Matlab code:

```
figure(1)
sys = tf([1 1], [1 2 1 0]);
step(sys);

figure(2)
s = tf('s');
GH = (1 + s) / (s*(s+1)^2);
rlocus(GH);
```

Answer (score 1):

The root locus is all the possible roots of a *closed loop system* that has an *open loop transfer function* $k G(s)$, when the gain is varied in the range $k \in (0, \infty)$ then $G(s)$, itself, does not have to be stable.

Try it again, only in closed loop with an open-loop gain of $\frac 2 9 G(s)$.